# Extracting a string between two strings

Tags: sed

I have a file, `ABDC.DELTA00.TS.D20161022.TS_BAR99.DAT.DOCC`.

I want to cut the text between two strings: the first `TS` and `DOCC`. I tried

```
efvar4=$(echo $filename | sed -n "s/.*TS//;s/DOCC.*//p")
```

resulting in `_BAR99.DAT` – matching the second `TS` in the filename.

Desired result: `.TS.D20161022.TS_BAR99.DAT.`

How do I modify my sed command to achieve the desired result?

Comment: regexes are greedy. so `.*TS` will match as much of the string as possible, which means it'll match the LAST `TS` in the string.

Comment: Thanks Marc B, is there a way to achieve desired result

Comment: `(TS.*\.DOCC)` instead? that'll force it to match as much as possible between TS/DOCC, capturing the "second" one as part of that.

Comment: Marc - I am very new to this sed, can you help me in writing the complete command

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "ABDC.DELTA00.TS.D20161022.TS_BAR99.DAT.DOCC" | sed 's/^.*\.TS\./.TS./;s/\.DOCC/./'
```

Comment: awesome, it works.. i will try calling them through variables.

Comment: Stro - I tried calling in variables, but i am not getting the same result .

==> echo $v1
TS
==> echo $v2
DOCC

==> echo $filename
ABDC.DELTA00.TS.D20161022.TS_BAR99.DAT.DOCC

==> echo $filename | sed "s/^.*\.$v1\./.$v1./;s/\$v2>
.TS.D20161022.TS_BAR99.DAT.DOCC

Desired result : .D20161022.TS_BAR99.DAT.

Comment: ```#!/bin/bash  
v1=TS  
v2=DOCC  
filename=ABDC.DELTA00.TS.D20161022.TS_BAR99.DAT.DOCC  
  
echo $filename | sed "s/^.*\.$v1\./.$v1./;s/\.$v2//"   ```

Comment: thank you. echo $filename | sed "s/^.*\.$v1\./.$v1./;s/\.$v2//"

.TS.D20161022.TS_BAR99.DAT

I want to remove 1st TS also and like to get a result like below : 
.D20161022.TS_BAR99.DAT

Comment: sure, can you figure it out?  (hint: look at first substitution)

Comment: Yes got it :-) 

You are awesome . echo $filename | sed "s/^.*\.$v1\././;s/\.$v2//"

.D20161022.TS_BAR99.DAT

i want "." after DAT as well, can you give me a hint for that too.

Comment: sure, just as easy, check 2nd substitution.

Comment: cool, 

==> echo $filename | sed "s/^.*\.$v1\././;s/\.$v2/./"
.D20161022.TS_BAR99.DAT.

I would like to get some training from you, can you please send email to yogu.shelly@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Strobelight, I am willing to pay for the training classes. Please let me know